# Salesforce setup an Approval Process with email template help

Tags: salesforce, email-templates

New to Salesforce and having some issues with the Approval Process setup. I have combed the web looking for solutions but nothing is working, uhg.

I have a multi set approval process in place and that part is working fine, what I need is a email template (Which I think I have but not a good one) that I can reply Yes, Y, Approve or No, N, Reject, etc... to approval/reject the case.

When the approver replies by email it just sends me an email to the case owner and not to salesforce, what am I doing wrong?

Sorry I don't think I should post any code here as it pertains to internal operations.

Thanks for any help on this,

--Phill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok well after much search on the web I did find the solution for replying by email, very simple.

Under:
Set up -> Create -> Workflow & Approvals -> Settings

You need to enable Email Approval Response option, this will generate an email that looks to be from the user who created it but when you hit reply you will see the user to whom you're replying to will change to the SF Approval Process Reply email.

Comment: sux I don't even get the rep points back that I used to create the bounty, oh well